# How to retrieve Google Maps client id?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I copy this code to create my first program with maps in java script

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-&sensor=false&v=3.7" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I run this program I got error message:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. This site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client id provided. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn more about registering URLs here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/guide.html#URLs

I saw that I need to add the parameter client to the link.

How I can know what is the ID of my client?

Comment: Start at the beginning: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial You don't need a Premier Client ID unless you are a Premier Client and have paid a lot of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page you link to:

> When registering for Google Maps API for Business, you will receive this client ID from Google Enterprise Support.